# Change tick frequency in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3.js. I've got a plot and the frequency of the ticks in my graph goes in each two days.

Example: 01/10 - 03/10 - 05/10 - 07/10..

The results I'm showing in this graph have one value per day.

Is there a way to set the ticks to be shown day by day?

Comment: Is my solution fit you? If you have any question feel to ask.

Comment: Yes, I just tested here. It worked well. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default nvd3/d3 defines the number of ticks at its discretion. You should specify `tickValues` for customization. Look at this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8t0tzhv/2/)

Currenly, there is the same problem what you describe.
Try to uncomment `tickValues` method, and you will get what you need - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsbvdq67/1/)

```
chart
  .xAxis
  .axisLabel("Date (m/y)")
  .tickValues(function (d) {
    return d[0].values.map(function (item) {
        return item.x;
    });
  })
  .tickFormat(function (d) {
      return d3.time.format("%m/%y")(new Date(d))
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`chart.reduceXTicks(false)`

By default `NVD3` shows reduced ticks.